# Magento 2.3.2 Megamenu error Declaration _getHtml

Tags: magento2, error, magento2.3, megamenu

Megamenu error After Upgrade Magento 2.3.2

Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Argument 4 passed to Ibnab\MegaMenu\Block\Html\Topmega::_getHtml() must be of the type array, null given

```
app\code\Ibnab\MegaMenu\Block\Html\Topmega.php on line 169
Ibnab\MegaMenu\Block\Html\Topmega->_getHtml(Object(Magento\Framework\Data\Tree\Node), 'submenu', 0, NULL)
Ibnab\MegaMenu\Block\Html\Topmega->_addSubMenu2(Object(Magento\Framework\Data\Tree\Node), 0, 'submenu', 0) 
Ibnab\MegaMenu\Block\Html\Topmega->_getHtml2(Object(Magento\Framework\Data\Tree\Node), 'submenu', 0)
```

Answer (score 3):

Edit following class and replace following code:

> Ibnab\MegaMenu\Block\Html\Topmega

```
protected function _getHtml(
    \Magento\Framework\Data\Tree\Node $menuTree,
    $childrenWrapClass,
    $limit,
    array $colBrakes = []
) {
```

Comment: after above change

Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Argument 4 passed to Ibnab\MegaMenu\Block\Html\Topmega::_getHtml() must be of the type array, null given

Comment: After applied my answer, you should check from where called this method. Passes third parameter to array except null.

Comment: $this->_getHtml($menuTree, 'submenu', 0, NULL) will replace $this->_getHtml($menuTree, 'submenu', 0, [])

Comment: sorry ,it's not working  :)

Comment: Not sure how you test. Your 4th param should be an array but when you call you pass null data. So replace null by array.

Comment: Install this module on 2.3.2 and create 3 level child category you get same error on category page

Comment: I have solved this replace with  : $colStops = null; to $colStops = [];